# infowindow closing and var (google maps api v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problem with closing infowindow when new is open in google maps api v.3.

```
var infowindow;
function addMarker(id, location) {
contentString = 'some content';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    maxWidth: 200
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  if (infowindow) infowindow.close();  
  infowindow.open(map, marker); 
});

markersArray[id] = marker;
}
```

The problem is that in above code the old infowindow is not close when new one is clicked unless I delete **var** from the line *var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({*
But then all the infowindows have the same content...

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: you are declaring two variables with same name in the same scope?

Comment: yes, its true. I have twice var infowindow. But when I remove _var infowindow; _ doesnt really change anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a global variable to contain a pointer to the last opened marker, and when opening a new one, close the previous one. Like this

```
//var infowindow; // <-- removed; should not be global
var openedInfoWindow = null;  // <-- added this here; make sure it's global

function addMarker(id, location) {
    contentString = 'some content';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 200
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (openedInfoWindow != null) openedInfoWindow.close();  // <-- changed this
      infowindow.open(map, marker); 
      // added next 4 lines
      openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          openedInfoWindow = null;
      });
    });

    markersArray[id] = marker;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I spend so much time trying to solve it out.

Comment: I don't know how this is different from the code I wrote but this worked and mine didn't so: upvote submitted Thanks