# infoBubble nothing display on gmappanel - EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs, extjs4, infobubble

```
function addDoctorLocation(options) 
{
    var gm = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap');
    var mpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat,options.lng);
    var marker = gm.addMarker(mpoint,options.marker,false,false, options.listeners);
    infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            map: gm,
            content: '<div class="phoneytext">Some label</div>',
            //position: new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat, options.lng),
            shadowStyle: 1,
            padding: '10px',
            //backgroundColor: 'rgb(57,57,57)',
            borderRadius: 5,
            minWidth: 200,
            arrowSize: 10,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
            disableAutoPan: true,
            hideCloseButton: false,
            arrowPosition: 7,
            backgroundClassName: 'phoney',
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(130, 120),
            arrowStyle: 2
        });
        infoBubble.open(map, marker);

}
```

Success added the marker on map, unfortunately infoBubble nothing has shown? why?
and dont have any error on FireBug

### UPDATE HOW TO CALL THE FUNCTION

```
tree.on('checkchange', function(node){
        var data = node.data;      
        if (data.checked == true){
        var lati,longi; 
        var record = MarkerStore.findRecord('MainID', data.MainID)
        if (record){
        lati = record.get('Latitude'); 
        longi = record.get('Longitude'); 
        }else{
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Error !',
        msg: 'No Record Found In Database ! <br />',
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
        }); 
        }       
        var options = {
        lat:lati,
        lng:longi,
        marker: {title:"Hello World!"},
        listeners: {
                     click: function(e){

                                         }
                    },
                    MainID: data.MainID     
        }     
        addDoctorLocation(options);  
        } else {
        markers[data.MainID].setMap(null);
    }   
    })
```

### UPPDATE For @Ankit

```
var markers = {};
var openedInfoWindow = null;    
function addDoctorLocation(options) 
{
    var gm = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap');
    var mpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat,options.lng);
    var marker = gm.addMarker(mpoint,options.marker,false,false, options.listeners);
    markers[options.MainID] = marker;

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Hello !',
        maxWidth: 200
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        // added next 4 lines

      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          openedInfoWindow = null;
      });

      if (openedInfoWindow != null) openedInfoWindow.close();  // <-- changed this
      openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
      infowindow.open(gm, marker); 

    });
```

still can't close the infowindow,when clicked marker get this error

```
TypeError: b.O is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

(82 out of range 43)
```

Comment: How are you calling addDoctorLocation in your code?

Comment: Try my answer posted below and check out other details

Comment: There is also discussion going on at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165007/google-maps-custom-infobox#comment21359522_15165007 you want to check out about style

Comment: @Ankit InfoBubble css style is more nicer than InfoBox, i dont like InfoBox

Comment: Chin Ye, we don't have choice here. You can not style Infowindow. If you want custom bubble than you have to go with infobox.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addDoctorLocation(options) 
{
 var gm = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap');
 var mpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat,options.lng);
 var marker = gm.addMarker(mpoint,options.marker,false,false, options.listeners);
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "Some label"});    
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(gm,marker) {
                    infowindow.open(gm, marker); // if still you can not open than use infowindow.open(gm, this)
            })
}
```

but looks like you want to style your infowindow than better use infobox instead of infowindow. Check you about InfoBox ->[Styling InfoWindow with Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140803/styling-infowindow-with-google-maps-api#comment21316211_15140803)

You can add some html tags like br, bold to infowindow content but I think you can not style infowindow.

Comment: FireBug Error `Error: Invalid value for property <map>: [object Object]` , my map is gmappanel v3 ,EXTJS 4

Comment: Ya I missed that sorry about that. More on Monday

Comment: The problem is because we are passing extjs gmappanel instance instead of Google maps instance. you need to create Google maps instance with marker info you have and pass it inside infowindow.open

Comment: when other check box are checked, and how to hide all info window? what i mean is,hide all infowindow first,then show the infowindow on addDoctorLocation. if not too many check box are checked, will show so much infowindow on google map

Comment: `infowindow.open(gm, this);` @Ankit your code can work for open infowindow,but can't close the infowindow when click the x on the top right.

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441157/infowindow-closing-and-var-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: still can't close infowindow,see the above code i have updated

Answer (score 0):

I try your example with google maps intstance and it works fine:

```
var markers = {};
var infowindow;
var openedInfoWindow = null;
var centerPointDefault = new google.maps.LatLng(39.739, -98.984);
function DrawMainMap(centerMap) {
    var myOptions = {
        center: centerMap,
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}
$(document).ready(function () {

var options = {
    lat: centerPointDefault.lat(),
    lng: centerPointDefault.lng(),
    marker: { title: "Hello World!" },
    listeners: {
        click: function(e) {

        }
    }
};

DrawMainMap(centerPointDefault);
addDoctorLocation(options);
}
function addDoctorLocation(options) {
var mpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat, options.lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mpoint
    });
marker.setMap(map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello !',
    maxWidth: 200
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // added next 4 lines

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
        openedInfoWindow = null;
    });

    if (openedInfoWindow != null) openedInfoWindow.close(); // <-- changed this
    openedInfoWindow = infowindow;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

});
}
```

Comment: i think u should try to use EXTJS 4 GmapPanel instead of google map.